# Python regex matching multiline string

Tags: python, regex

my_str :

```
PCT Filing Date: 2 December 2015
\nApplicants: Silixa Ltd.
\nChevron U.S.A. Inc. (Incorporated
in USA - California)
\nInventors: Farhadiroushan,
Mahmoud
\nGillies, Arran
Parker, Tom'
```

my code

```
regex = re.compile(r'(Applicants:)( )?(.*)', re.MULTILINE)
print(regex.findall(text))
```

my output :

```
[('Applicants:', ' ', 'Silixa Ltd.')]
```

what I need is to get the string between 'Applicants:' and  '\nInventors:'

```
'Silixa Ltd.' & 'Chevron U.S.A. Inc. (Incorporated
in USA - California)'
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If you want the regex to stop at `Inventors`, why are you using `.*`?

Comment: Should `Inventors:` and `Applicants:` always be at the start of the line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using re.DOTALL instead:

```
import re

text='''PCT Filing Date: 2 December 2015
\nApplicants: Silixa Ltd.
\nChevron U.S.A. Inc. (Incorporated
in USA - California)
\nInventors: Farhadiroushan,
Mahmoud
\nGillies, Arran
Parker, Tom'''

regex = re.compile(r'Applicants:(.*?)Inventors:', re.DOTALL)
print(regex.findall(text))
```

gives me

```
$ python test.py
[' Silixa Ltd.\n\nChevron U.S.A. Inc. (Incorporated\nin USA - California)\n\n']
```

The reason this works is that MULTILINE doesn't let the dot (.) match newlines, whereas DOTALL will.

Comment: You might want to clarify in your answer that MULTILINE is not needed here. It's not in your code, but you might explain why in the text. (Spoiler alert: MULTILINE affects the behaviour of `^` and `$` around newlines, but the OP's regex does not use `^` or `$`.)

Comment: Thank you so much for you help

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is the contents between `Applicants:` and `\nInventors:`, your regex should reflect that:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'Applicants: (.*)Inventors:', re.S)
>>> print(regex.findall(s))
['Silixa Ltd.\n\nChevron U.S.A. Inc. (Incorporated\nin USA - California)\n']
```

`re.S` is the "dot matches all" option, so our `(.*)` will also match new lines. Note that this is different from `re.MULTILINE`, because `re.MULTILINE` only says that our expression should apply to multiple lines, but doesn't change the fact `.` will not match newlines. If `.` doesn't match newlines, a match like `(.*)` will still stop at newlines, not achieving the multiline effect you want.

Also note that if you are not interested in `Applicants:` or `Inventors:` you may not want to put that between `()`, as in `(Inventors:)` in your regex, because the match will try to create a matching group for it. That's the reason you got 3 elements in your output instead of just 1.

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and explantations.. You made it look simple !!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match all the text between `\nApplicants:` and `\nInventors:`, you could also get the match without using `re.DOTALL` preventing unnecessary backtracking.

Match `Applicants:` and capture in group 1 the rest of that same line and all lines that follow that do not start with `Inventors:`

Then match Inventors.

```
^Applicants: (.*(?:\r?\n(?!Inventors:).*)*)\r?\nInventors:
```

- `^` Start of string (Or use `\b` if it does not have to be at the start)
- `Applicants:`  Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
  - `(?:\r?\n(?!Inventors:).*)*` Match all lines that do not start with Inverntors:
- `)` Close group
- `\r?\nInventors:` Match a newline and Inventors:

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1MtDtn/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9PAuLL)

Example code

```
import re
text = ("PCT Filing Date: 2 December 2015\n"
    "Applicants: Silixa Ltd.\n"
    "Chevron U.S.A. Inc. (Incorporated\n"
    "in USA - California)\n"
    "Inventors: Farhadiroushan,\n"
    "Mahmoud\n"
    "Gillies, Arran\n"
    "Parker, Tom'")
regex = re.compile(r'^Applicants: (.*(?:\r?\n(?!Inventors:).*)*)\r?\nInventors:', re.MULTILINE)
print(regex.findall(text))
```

Output

```
['Silixa Ltd.\nChevron U.S.A. Inc. (Incorporated\nin USA - California)']
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just had to remove ^ and then it's works perfectly : 
regex = re.compile(r'Applicants: (.*(?:\r?\n(?!Inventors:).*)*)\r?\nInventors:')

Comment: You can do that if it does not have to be at the start of the string. I would suggest prepending a word boundary `\b` in that case `\bApplicants: (.*(?:\r?\n(?!Inventors:).*)*)\r?\nInventors:` https://regex101.com/r/r7W0Ig/1

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more general approach to parse a string like that into a dict of all the keys and values in it (ie, any string at the start of a line followed by a `:` is a key and the string following that key is data):

```
import re 

txt="""\
PCT Filing Date: 2 December 2015
Applicants: Silixa Ltd.
Chevron U.S.A. Inc. (Incorporated
in USA - California)
Inventors: Farhadiroushan,
Mahmoud
Gillies, Arran
Parker, Tom'"""

pat=re.compile(r'(^[^\n:]+):[ \t]*([\s\S]*?(?=(?:^[^\n:]*:)|\Z))', flags=re.M)
data={m.group(1):m.group(2) for m in pat.finditer(txt)}
```

Result:

```
>>> data
{'PCT Filing Date': '2 December 2015\n', 'Applicants': 'Silixa Ltd.\nChevron U.S.A. Inc. (Incorporated\nin USA - California)\n', 'Inventors': "Farhadiroushan,\nMahmoud\nGillies, Arran\nParker, Tom'"}

>>> data['Applicants']
'Silixa Ltd.\nChevron U.S.A. Inc. (Incorporated\nin USA - California)\n'
```

[Demo of the regex](https://regex101.com/r/4s6vTK/1/)